# Transforming semidefinite program into generalized eigenvalue problem (GEVP)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

Suppose we have the following optimization problem on $r\in \mathbb{R}$ with constraint on positive definite matrices $A,B$

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{minimize } &\; r\\
\text{subject to } &\; A \prec r B 
\end{eqnarray}

What is a good way to show that solution is the largest generalized eigenvalue, using the definition of generalized eigenvalue from page 102 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook):

[image]

Comment: Small technical detail is that you should have a non-strict inequality, as the generalized eigenvalue if the value $r$ for which the inequality no longer is strict, i.e. the value for which $\det (A-rB)=0$

Comment: According to page 10 of [this book](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/lmibook), it's already a GEVP. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Updated question for clarity

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that by assumption of $A\in S^n$ and $B\in S^n_{++}$ (e.g. that $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is symmetric positive definite). Then

$$
A\prec r B \iff \sup_{\|u\|_2 =1 }u^T(A-rB)u < 0. \quad (*)
$$
Define $\bar u$ by the generalized eigenvalue (the $u$ that achieves the supremum in $(*)$).
Since $B$ is symmetric positive definite, then for any $u\neq 0$, $u^TBu> 0$, so $(*)$ is equivalent to
$$
\frac{\bar u^TA\bar u}{ \bar u^TB\bar u }  < r.
$$
Since the problem is to minimize $r$, the optimal solution to the SDP is in fact
$$
\frac{\bar u^TA\bar u}{ \bar u^TB\bar u }  = r.
$$

It is left to show that
$$
\frac{\bar u^TA\bar u}{ \bar u^TB\bar u }  = \sup_u \frac{u^TAu}{ u^TBu }=\lambda_{\max}(A,B) .
$$
Assume that it is not true, e.g. there exists $\hat u$ where $$\frac{\hat u^TA\hat u}{\hat u^TB\hat u} - \xi=  \frac{\bar u^TA\bar u}{ \bar u^TB\bar u } = r, \quad \xi > 0. $$
Then
$$
\hat u^T(A-rB)\hat u  = \xi \hat u^TB\hat u> 0 > \sup_{\|u\|_2=1}u^T(A-rB)u
$$
which is not possible. Therefore $\lambda_{\max}(A,B) = r$.